# Refactoring a regular expression check in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, refactoring

I'm thinking there has got to be a cleaner way to check if a regular expression is not nil / is true.  This is what I have been using:
hold = (h4.text =~ /Blah/)
if !hold.nil?
  ...
end

I tried: !(h4.text =~ /Blah/).nil? but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

text = 'Blah blah blah'
puts "blah" if text =~ /Blah/    # => blah

text = 'Foo bar baz'
puts "blah" if text =~ /Blah/    # (nothing printed)
```

- In a Ruby conditional statement,
  anything that is neither nil nor
  false is considered to be true.
- =~ returns nil for no match, or an integer character position if there
  is a match.
- nil is as good a false; an integer is
  as good as true.

Therefore, you can use the result of =~ directly in an if, while, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unless` here:

```
unless h4.text =~ /Blah/
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if h4.text !~ /Blah/
   # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above seemed to work, this is what I ended up with:

```
unless (h4.text =~ /Blah/) == nil
   ...
end
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `if h4.text =~ /Blah/`, if that's what you're looking for?